Correct finite automata diagrams for these simple problems?
Hello I am learnign about finite automata and I want to see if these diagrams and my explanation make sense.
{w ∈ Σ∗ | w contains the substring 1010} using five states

There is the substring of 1010 in the states. If you broke the substring you need to loop back
Accept state with either 0 or 1 as the ending


w ∈ Σ∗ | w contains exactly two 0s, or at least two 1s} using six states.

Start with pre state
Two paths: The first path is for two 0s. There is no loops for the 0s. The second path is the 1s, there needs to be at least 2 and go up to infinite
E is epsilon. Do I need 0s as loops on C and D?



You have provided two finite Automata question,
1:
In your first diagram edge from state D to state C with input symbol 0 is not making any difference.
2:
In your second diagram loop of 0 is required on state C and D in second path.
In first path of second diagram, you need to add one more state as 1010 is valid string as per your question but it is not accepted by your provided diagram so your diagram is like,

